# How to get values from an array adapter?

Tags: java, android

I have some text from voice recognition.

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    match_text_dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        match_text_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog_matches_frag);
    textlist = (ListView)match_text_dialog.findViewById(R.id.list);
    matches_text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matches_text);
    textlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    textlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
            Speech.setText("You have said " +matches_text.get(position));
            match_text_dialog.hide();
        }
    });
    match_text_dialog.show();
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Then i developed a code for get some specific text.

```
String sentence = stop.getText().toString();
String[] splitWords = sentence.split(" ");
String[] stopWords = {"I", "want", "to", "go", "to", "the"};

for (int i = 0; i < stopWords.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < splitWords.length; j++) {
        if (stopWords[i].equalsIgnoreCase(splitWords[j])) {
            splitWords[j] = null;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < splitWords.length; i++) {
    if(splitWords[i]!= null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),splitWords[i] , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

What i want to do is get ArrayAdapter values and pass it to my second code.
How do i get values and pass it to String sentence ??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me get this straight... when do you want to pass the string into `String sentence`? When the list item is clicked?

If so, make a method, put the 2nd bit of the code inside the method, and take in the string as an argument... Simple really..

```
public void goToMethod(String sentence) {
         //put the String sentence code here
         String sentence;
         this.sentence = sentence;

         String[] splitWords = sentence.split(" ");
         String[] stopWords = {"I", "want", "to", "go", "to", "the"};

         for (int i = 0; i < stopWords.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < splitWords.length; j++) {
                   if (stopWords[i].equalsIgnoreCase(splitWords[j])) {
                           splitWords[j] = null;
                   }
               }
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < splitWords.length; i++) {
             if(splitWords[i]!= null) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),splitWords[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }
}
```

And then, from the `onItemClick()` method in the Activity, call this method that you created.

```
public void onItemClick(....) {
        Speech.setText("You have said " +matches_text.get(position));
        match_text_dialog.hide();
        goToMethod(matches_text.get(position));
}
```

you cannot take text directly out from `AdapterView`. It doesnt work that way. That is why you get the int position argument, to manipulate the array that was fed in.. :")